# Remapping several faces for use in minor mode

Tags: org-mode, faces, minor-mode

I'm using `face-remap-add-relative` in a tiny minor mode which, when activated, increases the size of the `org-level-1` face. This function is perfect for that because when evaluated it returns a cookie that can be kept for later restoring the original size of the modified face. Here's the code:

```el
(defvar bigger-org-headlines-cookie nil)

(make-variable-buffer-local 'bigger-org-headlines-cookie)

(define-minor-mode bigger-org-headlines
  "Increases the size of level 1 Org headlines."
  :lighter " Big-Org-Headlines"
  (if bigger-org-headlines
      (setq bigger-org-headlines-cookie
            (face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-1
                                     :height
                                     (expt text-scale-mode-step 1)))
    (face-remap-remove-relative bigger-org-headlines-cookie))
  (force-window-update (current-buffer)))
```

Now I changed my mind and want to increase the size of every headline in an Org file. In total there are 8 levels that need to be changed.

Is there an easier way besides changing `face-remapping-alist` manually (which BTW is [not recommended](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html#Face-Remapping))?

Suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a straightforward application for `map`.  Try this:

```el
(defvar bigger-org-headlines-cookies nil) 

(make-variable-buffer-local 'bigger-org-headlines-cookies)

(define-minor-mode bigger-org-headlines
  "Make Org headlines bigger."
  :lighter " Big-Org-Headlines"
  (if bigger-org-headlines 
      (mapc (lambda (face)
              (push (face-remap-add-relative face :height text-scale-mode-step)
                    bigger-org-headlines-cookies))
            (cons 'org-link org-level-faces))
    (mapc #'face-remap-remove-relative bigger-org-headlines-cookies)
    (setq bigger-org-headlines-cookies nil))
  (force-window-update (current-buffer)))
```

Note that your code errored for me until I added the docstring.

I also removed your `expt` call since it wasn't doing anything.  Feel free to reinstate it if it was just standing in for a calculation as-yet unimplemented.

In testing, I found that links weren't being affected, so I went ahead and added the `org-link` face, too.

Comment: Yes, that's it; making the cookie variable a list of cookies did the trick. Didn't knew about `org-level-faces`, thanks! However there are some misplaced parens in your code. Also, `mapcar` could be replaced with `mapc` since only the side-effects are important here. The call to `apply-partially` also seems unnecessary. Do you mind to edit it before accepting your answer?

Comment: Not at all.  Done.  Thanks in particular for pointing out `mapc`; I hadn't previously been aware of it.  Also, I did some testing and noticed that links weren't being affected, so I tacked on the `org-link` face.